# How do I get only the second column of a CSV file using PHP?

Tags: php, cakephp, csv, cakephp-1.3

I have the csv file(test.csv) and have the text as below:

```
1,maly,maly(),f,df
2,cheata,aaa,df,df
3,cheata,df,df,df
4,maly,fc,cfv,f
5,maly,df,fg,fg
6,chantha,fc,gf,fg
7,chantha,gh,a,g
8,David,fgfd,dfg,g
```

**What I want:**

I want to diplay only:`maly cheata chantha David`.For the name that have two or more the same,take only one.And I have the php code as below:

```
$c=0;   
$data=fopen('test.csv','r');
while($row=fgets($data)){
if($c!=0){
echo $row[3]."<br>\n";
}
$c++;
}
```

**The problem is**

It does not display what I want. It displays

> h h a a h h a

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you were intending to call `fgetcsv` instead of `fgets`. Also, the `name` index would be `1` then, instead of `3`:

```
<?php

$file = fopen('test.csv', 'r');
while($row = fgetcsv($file)) {
    if (isset($row[1])) {
        echo $row[1], "\n";
    }
}
fclose($file);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`fgetcsv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) instead of `fgets`.

```
if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        if (isset($data[1])) {
            echo $data[1] . "<br>\n";
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your anwser, It works but It displays:maly cheata cheata maly maly chantha chantha David.For me I want to display:maly cheata chantha David. Please help me,Thanks,

Comment: @user1606816 What is the rule to select data?

Comment: I used your code than it will be display what wrote but I do not want to display like this.

Comment: If you only want unique names from the second column, you'll need to build a $names array rather than just outputting the names as you read them. So instead of echo $data[1] use $names[$data[1]] = $data[1]. Then loop over the names array to output the results.

Answer (score 0):

The `file` method returns all lines in an array. The `explode` method splits up a line by a particular delimiter.

```
$lines = file($file_name);

$fields = array();
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    $cells = explode(',', $line);
    $fields[] = $cells[1];
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($fields);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: You could similarly explode on PHP_EOL in place of lines.

Comment: @MaxPRafferty I think you're talking about `file_get_contents`. `file` already does both *and* it might even be able to `auto_detect_line_endings` (depends on settings), which a strict `PHP_EOL` wouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

You're heading does not match your question, you want the second column, not row.

Firstly, your getting the 4th character of each row you need to do something like this (not tested):

```
$data=fopen('test.csv','r');
while($row=fgets($data)){
   $cols =  explode(',' $row);
   echo $cols[1]."<br>\n";
}
```